# In recursion function parameter value getting change according to down recursion value

Tags: java, recursion

In following code, the variable `levelsToGo` is getting updated unexpectedly on the recursive invocation of `getAllStringNames()`. When it comes back to stack to pop I am getting value of levelsToGo that was passed into the recursive call, not the value that existed previously.

```
public List<String> getAllStringNames(Student p, Integer levelsToGo)
{
    List<String> employeeSet = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(Student child : p.getAllSubjects())
    {
      employeeSet.add(child.getRoll());
      if(levelsToGo > 0)
      studentChilds.addAll(getAllStringNames(child, --levelsToGo))
    }

    return employeeSet;
}
```

The first time I passed student1, `levelsToGo` was 1 and student1 had 1 child. It called recursively and set `levelsToGo` to 0. When it came back to the first iteration we found that value is still 0. It should be the original value 1.

Comment: A sample input and expected output?

Comment: Are you expecting changes to `levelsToGo` in inner recursive calls to be reflected in outer recursive calls?

Comment: This is really stupid thing i have done :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You decrement `levelsToGo` when you use it in the `getAllStringNames()` method invocation. The expression `--levelsToGo` means subtract one from the value of `levelsToGo`, *store it back into `levelsToGo`*, and then use it in the method call.

Instead, you should write

```
studentChilds.addAll(getAllStringNames(child, levelsToGo - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not decrement integer variable, pass new integer as parameter

```
studentChilds.addAll(getAllStringNames(child, levelsToGo - 1))
```